# MacRuby ScriptingBridge loading speed

Tags: macruby, adobe-indesign, scripting-bridge

Is there a faster way to load scripting bridge applications from MacRuby?

When I make the SBApplication object for Adobe InDesign it takes more than 10 seconds to load. Here's the code I've been using:

```
framework 'ScriptingBridge'

indesign = SBApplication.applicationWithBundleIdentifier("com.adobe.InDesign")

puts indesign
```

Of course the generated header file is huge for InDesign... Is there a way to force the use of a support file?

Comment: This seems like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8830436/is-it-possible-to-reduce-the-startup-time-of-macruby-scripts-which-use-the-scrip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The large load time when using ScriptingBridge is a documented issue.  An alternative is [macruby-appscript](https://github.com/dnagir/appscript/tree/master/macruby-appscript/trunk).

Comment: Is there any way to load a support file or the headers before hand?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by before hand.  The files will have to be loaded at some point.

Comment: Before the script is run. I'm assuming each time it is run, the scripting bridge is generating whatever files it needs to communicate with the application. The time consuming part of the "loading" is either the generating or just getting it into memory? If you could generate them before hand it might load faster?

Comment: Have a look at `gen_bridge_metadata`.  I've used it for frameworks, but it should also work for a set of headers.

Comment: Appscript is effectively deprecated, so this isn't really a viable option.